# How to check ac current on ac adapter with dmm?

Tags: current, multimeter, amperage

I tried by plugging the red cable into '10a' (measures current between some milliamps value to 10 amp, or so), and then putting black probe into the plug, then the red onto the jacket/outer part of the plug. The reading goes from some amp value, but quickly drops to zero, before getting a chance to note said amp value, while the ac adapter is plugged into an ac portable charger.

What's a likely cause?

Edit: Btw, the dmm value appears to also jump higher than amp output listed on the adapter (before dropping to 0)..

Comment: With a regular DMM you will need to cut into cables and insert the DMM in between. If you're just touching the pins you are shorting out the AC adapter and it is going into current limiting mode. A multimeter in current measuring mode appears as a piece of wire and acts as a short-circuit if you try and use it as if you were measuring a voltage.

Comment: Or do some dangerous things with plugs and sockets.

Comment: thanks, thought current would simply go from center pin, and 'ground' on outer, apparently not;).

Comment: @slackexchange Nope. Measuring current is like measuring flow. You gotta stick something right in the middle and have it flow through. So not as convenient as measuring voltage. Multimeter in current mode is like a big open pipe. So you can kinda see what happens if you stick that in like a voltage measurement. All the current flows the meter and bypasses the circuit.

Comment: @slackexchange - yes that is what happens - and that's where the problem is with your technique. Your meter acts like a short circuit when measuring current, so doing what you did short-circuits the power supply. If you're lucky then the supply just shuts down to protect itself. If you're less lucky then the results could range from a blown fuse in your meter to smoke & flames from the supply.

Comment: cool.. wondered also if there's be a way to probe the current going into the laptop's power jack, using circuitry to main board to measure the flow?

Answer (score 1):

First, think safe.  You'll be playing with lethal voltages here.  I'm *showing you how* to do this, but I *strongly recommend* that you get a clamp-on current meter.

Second, you need to build a test fixture to do this.  You're playing with lethal voltages here.  Poor workmanship can kill you or others.  Don't just do this with twisted wires and electrical tape.  solder it up properly and use heat shrink tubing over the joints, or use wire nuts.  Make sure to get, and use, shrouded banana plugs so that there's no bare metal that can be easily touched if things come unplugged while you're doing your testing.

Or get a clamp-on current meter.

Here's a picture.  You can build one of these from an extension cord.  Cut one of the wires, extend them a bit, and put a **shrouded** banana plug on each end.  These will plug into your meter.  Your meter's chassis will now be hot, so if the case is broken, you'll be exposing yourself or others to potentially lethal voltages.

Or get a clamp-on current meter.

Plug your appliance in to the socket end of the cord, plug your cord's banana plugs into the meter, then plug the cord into the wall.  At all times, remember that you're dealing with potentially lethal voltages.  Now you can take your readings.

Or get a clamp-on current meter.

[image]

Comment: appreciate it, might look into that.

Comment: And if you get a clamp meter, which you absolutely should do, you would want to use it alongside one of [these](https://www.amazon.com/Amprobe-ELS2A-AC-Line-Splitter/dp/B001DPR0FE), or the equivalent with your local type of plug on it. (this isn't a specific recommendation for that brand or anything, it's just the first search result.) And remember, just in case the answer above didn't make it clear, you should get a clamp meter.

Comment: @slackexchange What exactly are you trying to measure and why? It sounds like your'e trying to measure the output current of a 'wall-wart' type adapter. Can you tell us the ratings of the adapter and what it is powering? Are you trying to measure the current that the 'portable charger' you mentioned is drawing? If so you don't want to do it on the AC line side, you'd want to put the meter in series with the output.

Comment: And if _that's_ the case it's DC, and the voltages are (or should be) safe and isolated from line voltages, and -- just to confuse things -- you could easily get by _without_ a clamp meter.

Comment: holy,  thought one could simply  put a conductor into the adapter plug, and the other end of it to a metal surface and measure current in between, with dmm probes.. btw, it's ac adapter for laptop.